# Homomorphism from the symmetric group onto $\{1, -1\}$ with kernel $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Consider the map 
$\epsilon(\sigma) := \prod_{i<j}\frac{(\sigma(j)-\sigma(i))}{j-i}$ for $\sigma \in S_n$. Now we are to show that 
(1) this map is onto $\{-1, 1\}$, that's fairly easy and that (2) the map is a homomorphism. How do we do that? I can't see a way to prove that
$\prod_{i<j}\frac{\sigma(\pi(j)) - \sigma(\pi(i))}{j-i} = \prod_{i<j}\frac{(\sigma(j)-\sigma(i))}{j-i} .\prod_{i<j}\frac{(\pi(j)-\pi(i))}{j-i}$ .

I know that $\prod_{i<j} (\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)) = \mathrm{det}(V)$ is the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix with entries $V_{i,j} = \sigma(i)^{j-1}$, but I can't really see how that helps either (supposing it is helpful at all)...

The exercise finishes with demanding to prove that $\mathrm{ker} (\epsilon) = A_n$.

Help is very appreciated!

Comment: You can't really use determinants in this, because on a closer inspection it would make the argument circular.

Comment: Check it for the product ot two transpositions, since they generate the symmetric group.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Not necessarily ; you can define the determinant without using the notion of signature. The definition of the signature that I have learned was as the determinant of the corresponding permutation matrix.

Comment: @ArnaudD. And how did you prove that $\dim\bigwedge^n \Bbb R^{n*}=1$ without knowing that any two decompositions in transpositions of a permutation $\sigma$ have the same parity?

Comment: That's not exactly how it was presented, but roughly speaking the existence of a decomposition in transpositions is enough to show that $\dim\bigwedge \Bbb R^n\leq 1$. For the other inequality, it is enough to give an example of non-zero alternating form, so you take a formula for the determinant, and show that it is multilinear and alternating.

Answer (score 2):

One way to prove it is the following : $\prod_{i<j}\frac{\sigma(\pi(j))-\sigma(\pi(i))}{j-i} = \prod_{i<j} \frac{\sigma(\pi(j))-\sigma(\pi(i))}{\pi(j)-\pi(i)}\frac{\pi(j)-\pi(i)}{j-i}$

And then you notice that in  $\prod_{i<j} \frac{\sigma(\pi(j))-\sigma(\pi(i))}{\pi(j)-\pi(i)}$, if you permute the indices, it's just $\prod_{i<j} \frac{\sigma(j)-\sigma(i)}{j-i}$, which proves that it's a morphism.